# Best Open Source CMS or library management plugin

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking for a open source or free wordpress CMS or library plugin to post 2,000 huge text articles with search keyword, highlighting like CMS to an existing site.

Could you please let me know which plugin provides a best search like search by keyword, search results displayed easily to navigate with shortcut keys, quickest search etc.,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**1. What is a CMS:**

"A content management system (CMS)is a computer application that supports the creation and modification of digital content using a common user interface and thus usually supporting multiple users working in a collaborative environment. CMSes have been available since the late 1990s."
(Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system)

1.1 Popular CMS Systems for websites:

- WordPress (https://wordpress.org/)
- Drupal (https://www.drupal.org/)
- Joomla (https://www.joomla.org/)

There are many more and all of them have different advantages and disadvantages.

**2. Example Solution with WordPress:**

2.1 First find your domain, buy it and install WordPress. Many hosts offer one-click installers for WordPress.

2.2 Find a theme (WordPress terminology for templates) you want to use. This will define the UX (user experience) for your website. These may include your requested search features for the different posts/articles.

You can find free themes here: https://wordpress.org/themes/

Paid "premium" themes here: https://themeforest.net/ (or other ressources)

2.3 Importing & Publishing all your posts: Use one of the many existing importing plugins (WordPress extensions) to import and publish your content.

So far the best plugin I used for importing huge amounts of content with the easiest interface is WP All Import (http://www.wpallimport.com/). It allows imports from different resources and plays well with all a lot of other plugins.

---

Final Note: I am not associated with any of the above mentioned solutions. The suggestions mentioned above are solely based on my personal experience.

Comment: I'm looking for plugin where i can post several contents and provide search. example 1. http://www.wordofthehour.net/#search/type=standard/query=rapture/library=branham/category=all/filter=/start=0/rows=10  2. lwbcast.org/Mobile   3. http://branham.ru/message/sermonwbd23b.html?all=2

Comment: one more example - http://blog.enyojs.com/post/22740623548/showcase-readontouch-pro

Comment: Any modern CMS will support provides basic search and advanced search. 
For example for WordPress based websites it is most of the time 
1. http://urldomain.com/?s=yoursearchterm
=> All posts/articles matching that search term
or with a little bit of code (which is sometime provided by the theme you need to select)
2. http://urldomain.com/?s=yoursearchterm&cat=yourcategory
=> All posts matching that search term in the matching category.

These two plugins could help you too:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/category-posts/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/display-posts-shortcode/

Comment: We are already using wordpress and built the site with wordpress...Could you please help me on how to efficiently do it? do we need to create separate pages for each article ? how to preparate table of contents ? how to provide type-ahead search

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking for. I gave you an option for a plugin to import a large amount of articles and also how you can make the articles be found in the front-end (with a theme and/or additional plugins). These should be all the tools you need to replicate one of your example website and features. If this goes beyond your capabilities, then I am afraid that you will need to ask a professional developer (or advanced WordPress admin) to help you with this task.